# Ways to debug root partition not unmounted on reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4, reboot, unmount

I have a problem where every time I reboot a Linux system (Ubuntu-based), the root filesystem is not unmounted successfully.

Doing a fsck after a reboot results in output like:

```
Recovering journal [...] clearing orphaned inode [...]
```

The message displayed on reboot is:

```
Failed to remount '/' as read-only: Device or resource busy
```

Is there a way to interrupt the reboot and get a command prompt inside the ramfs root filesystem used during reboot so I can debug things there? Like see what processes are in memory, inspect file handles etc.

Or have any other recommendations for getting to the root cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to switch to different runlevel in order to see if the error occur even without a full reboot.

You can check if your physicall disk is in a good state too, maybe it's damaged